# private static final field in singleton class

Tags: java, static, singleton, field, final

Are there any consequences declaring/not declaring a field in a singleton class static final or just final if it's private and only a accessible from the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are no consequences. Basically singleton is an instance (just one instance) so it is against design to have class member fields (static ones). I would avoid using static fields

Comment: I would appriciate a much more detailed answer, behind the scenes, java inner works, byte code level effective difference. The question was really about is it make difference or not? Like space/tab war....and not about design patterns.

Comment: Well singleton is a design pattern. Other than that it is a normal java class and what makes it a singleton is that you follow the pattern. If you talk java wise if you can have static final fields in singleton class - yes you can and it will not make any difference. It is a normal java class that can do what other java classes can. The compiler compiles it in the same way. It's on top level how you have designed it (not to allow more than on instances for example) but on low level it is a normal class. Unless you use an enum for singleton implementation but then ... it's the same ;)

Comment: Enums are also classes with their own methods extedning java.lang.Enum :) I need solid proof for difference between the 2 keywords combined in this way or maybe a solution how can I test it...

Answer (score 0):

The singleton design pattern is to ensure that there is only one instance of your class in the application run-time. This Singleton  object it will be used by other object in order to invoke it public methods, so you should expose a public static method to other objects in order to get an instance of the singleton , so the field should be static also.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with implementing the singleton pattern and accessing the singleton instance variable.

Comment: Ok, i see what you are asking for now. About this field if you will declare this field final you should initialize it,and with that can’t gain some memory if this field can be initialized lazy. And there is no difference between declaring a field static final private and only final private because static field will be shared with all instances of this object but you here you have a singleton so there is no difference .

Comment: We are getting closer, one of the differences is the field initialization must be made from the constructor or static block. But I need more...like byte code level difference. If it's just a constant for this class then there is no  real difference. Effective java says make immutable objects to achive thread safety.

Comment: Sure there is a difference between the byte-code generated in this cases by the JVM.About the thread safety, if this field is a constant that isn’t cause a multithreading problem, if not you should declare this field as an atomic field. If it is a primitive you can use atomicInteger or AtomicBoolean if not you can use AtomicReference class in order to ensure that your code is thread safe  .